# iOS: Application give bad access in uicollectioview cellForItemAtIndexPath while using in share extension

Tags: swift

I am using custom share extension in my application.When i am using collection view delegate method in my share viewcontroller class it gives me the bad **EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION** on making the uicollectionview cell object.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:  "cell", for: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionViewCell
     return cell
}
```

Comment: can you share some more code? Are you registering MediaCollectionViewCell for the reuse identifier "cell"?

Comment: there is no code in mediaCollectionViewCell class it gives EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION while creating the object of cell class. It also gives EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on default collection view class.

Comment: Are you registering anything for the reuse identifier "cell" anywhere in your code your Storyboard/Interface Builder?

Comment: yes  i register in storyboard

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of my question in my case i do not set the identifier of view controller in storyboard that it the reason for bad access.